# Xubuntu 20.04 does not start after a clean installation [SOLVED]

Tags: boot, xubuntu, 20.04

**System**: Acer Aspire 5542 laptop using legacy mode (UEFI is not available).
**Processor**: AMD Athlon II X2 M300
**Graphics**: ATI Radeon HD 4200
**Memory**: 4 GB

This system is currently running Xubuntu 18.04.4 LTS perfectly OK.

I decided to do a clean **Xubuntu 20.04** install on an external USB hard disk to test the new release and see how things would go. The system booted successfully from the USB stick I had created from the .iso file and the installation also completed successfully. The boot loader was placed on the USB hard disk so that the installation would be completely independent from any other hard disk.

And then... the post-installation reboot...

The system starts reading from the USB hard disk, the GRUB menu appears after an approximate 30 sec delay and the first option (*Ubuntu*) is executed automatically a few seconds later. That's it. The journey ends right there. The screen remains black and the system never completes its booting procedure.

I can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd> at this point and restart the system. I attempt to start in ***recovery mode*** on the GRUB menu after it appears again. The **Loading kernel 5.4.26...** line will appear 3-4 minutes later, the system will stay like that for 3-4 minutes more and then the **Loading initial ramdisk...** line will appear. End of story. This is as far as it goes.

Any suggestions please?

---

***UPDATE No 1***
I managed to install **Xubuntu 20.04** manually by executing `apt-get install xubuntu-desktop` after I finished a basic `focal-live-server` installation.

The system now boots successfully and I noticed that the installed kernel this time, was **5.4.28**. Is this the reason why this installation boots successfully?

Another thing I also noticed, was that `xubuntu-desktop` installed both `lightdm` and `gdm3` and that there were a lot of double/unnecessary icons on the right side of the top panel when the user's desktop appeared after the login. `xubuntu-desktop` does not perform the same installation as the iso probably.

---

***UPDATE No 2***
After the successful installation in the 1st update, I attempted another one from the iso. This time it was successful too. I enabled the downloading of both, updates and other software and the installer downloaded and installed kernel **5.4.28**. The system booted successfully after that and I guess the whole question can be closed now.

---

***UPDATE No 3***
Things can be tricky sometimes. It turns out the culprit was something completely unexpected. There seems to be an incompatibility with the **MBR** partitioning scheme. I tested this again and again. The system is facing the exact same problem, every time I attempt to install **20.04** on an **MBR** partitioned hard disk. The problem is not kernel **5.4.26** as I thought initially. Both kernels run correctly and the system boots every time if I use **GPT** on the installation disk.

As I have mentioned already, all installation attempts were made on an external USB hard disk. The next tests will be made on an internal SATA disk and if the results change, I'll update this question again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved in ***Update No 3***.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.. Weird.. Last night I had weird issues with the computing latency of my machine, which was really weird because my machine is powerful, and all i did was service the machine physically. It's was using 60% memory, after I booted up and I was only running a web browser and a terminal. Today I booted up and had this very problem. After reading the comments, I thought let me first try a simple reboot. It always best first out rule out obvious problems

```
$sudo shutdown --reboot
```

It turns out (for me) a major update was needed.. Well bigger than normal. Once the kernel, and the firmware was all updated, things now appear to be smooth. If the GUI/desktop doesn't give you a window to update, just open your terminal and update it from there.

```
$sudo apt update
```

It will then ask you to upgrade. Simply put in this command into your terminal.

```
$sudo apt upgrade
```

Say yes and it worked for me. Unfortunately it is wise to be familiar with the terminal if you want to use Linux OS's.  Perhaps you should use Livepatch? Some like it, some don't, I find it very handy personally. Im not entirely sure if livepatch will work with xfce or xubuntu. Happy hacking!